# How do i make a check if fields are filled cordova/angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, cordova

I have a question in my controller i have made a post for my data filled in my form of my cordova app. But if all fields are empty its still insert it in the database.

This is my code at the moment.

controller scope (add function)

```
$scope.addInvoice = function(){
    console.log($scope.fileToUpload);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var filedata = $scope.dataURLtoFile("data:image/jpeg;base64," + $rootScope.scan, 'scan.png');
    formdata.append("title", "Factuur " + $scope.factuurNr);
    formdata.append("imageselect", filedata);
    formdata.append("command", "Invoices:uploadImage");
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: gateway,
    data: formdata,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            swal("Geweldig!", "de bon is succesvol toegevoegd", "success");
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $scope.docGuid = data.data;
            $scope.$apply();
            // addInvoice \\
            // $ticket = $_POST['invoiceno'] ?: $_POST['ticket'] ?: null;
            // $totInclVat = $_POST['totamount'] ?: $_POST['totInclVat'] ?: null;
            // $docGuid = $_POST['docGuid'] ?: $_POST['docguid'] ?: null;
            // $vatLow = $_POST['vatLow'] ?: $_POST['vatlow'] ?: null;
            // $vatHigh = $_POST['vatHigh'] ?: $_POST['vathigh'] ?: null;
            // echo $api->addInvoiceOut($ticket, $_POST['company'], $_POST['person'], $totInclVat, $vatLow, $vatHigh, $_POST['concerns'], $docGuid);
            //END//
            if($scope.newContact){
                var type = "Bedrijf";
                var company = $scope.inputCompany;
                var formdata = $("").serializeArray();
                formdata.push({"name": "firstName", "value": company});
                formdata.push({"name": "type", "value": type});
                formdata.push({"name": "command", "value": "Contacts:add"});
                $.post(gateway, formdata, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var companyGuid = data.data;
                    var formdata = $("#bonForm").serializeArray();
                    formdata.push({"name": "company", "value": companyGuid});
                    formdata.push({"name": "docGuid", "value": $scope.docGuid});
                    formdata.push({"name": "person", "value": ""});
                    formdata.push({"name": "vatLow", "value": ""});
                    formdata.push({"name": "vatHigh", "value": ""});
                    formdata.push({"name": "billingStatus", "value": "60"});
                    formdata.push({"name": "command", "value": "Invoices:addInvoiceOut"});
                    $.post(gateway, formdata, function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        //admin_lifecycle
                        formdata.pop();
                        formdata.push({
                        "name": "vatcat",
                        "value": 0
                        });
                        formdata.push({
                        "name": "exvat",
                        "value": 0
                        });
                        formdata.push({
                        "name": "vat",
                        "value": 0
                        });
                        formdata.push({
                        "name": "command",
                        "value": "Invoices:addLifecycleLine"
                        });
                        $.post(gateway, formdata, function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }, "json");
                    }, "json");
                }, "json");
            }else{
                var formdata = $("#bonForm").serializeArray();
                formdata.push({"name": "company", "value": $scope.selectedCompany.guid});
                formdata.push({"name": "docGuid", "value": $scope.docGuid});
                formdata.push({"name": "person", "value": ""});
                formdata.push({"name": "vatLow", "value": ""});
                formdata.push({"name": "vatHigh", "value": ""});
                formdata.push({"name": "billingStatus", "value": "60"});
                formdata.push({"name": "command", "value": "Invoices:addInvoiceOut"});
                $.post(gateway, formdata, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // swal("Geweldig!", "de bon is succesvol toegevoegd", "success");
                    //admin_lifecycle
                    formdata.pop();
                    formdata.push({
                    "name": "vatcat",
                    "value": 0
                    });
                    formdata.push({
                    "name": "exvat",
                    "value": 0
                    });
                    formdata.push({
                    "name": "vat",
                    "value": 0
                    });
                    formdata.push({
                    "name": "command",
                    "value": "Invoices:addLifecycleLine"
                    });
                    $.post(gateway, formdata, function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }, "json");
                }, "json");
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

This is the input (FRONT)

```
<form id="bonForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 doc-check">
                    <input type="radio" ng-click="document=false" id="factuur" name="docCheck" checked>
                    <label ng-style="document == false && {'background':'#a44dac'}" for="factuur">Factuur</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 doc-check">
                    <input type="radio" ng-click="document=true" id="document" name="docCheck">
                    <label ng-style="document == true && {'background':'#a44dac'}" for="document">Document</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input id="company" class="form-fleximaal" name="company" type="text" ng-focus="focused = true" ng-model="inputCompany" placeholder="Bedrijf selecteren/zoeken"/>
                <ul class="input-dropdown" ng-show="focused" ng-mouseleave="focused = false">
                    <li class="dropdown-option" ng-repeat="companie in companies | filter:{name: inputCompany} " ng-click="addInputCompany(companie)">
                        <p><i class="fas fa-building"></i>{{companie.name}}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6" ng-hide="document">
            <input type="text" class="form-fleximaal" name="invoiceno" ng-model="factuurNr" placeholder="Factuur nr." required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6" ng-show="document">
            <input type="text" class="form-fleximaal" name="docnr" ng-model="documentNr" placeholder="Document nr." required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <input class="form-fleximaal" type="date" name="dateDeadline" ng-model="documentDatum" placeholder="Documentdatum" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-fleximaal" name="concerns" ng-model="betreft" placeholder="Betreft" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12" ng-hide="document">
            <input type="number" step="any" class="form-fleximaal" name="totamount" ng-model="inclprijs" placeholder="Prijs inclusief." required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <button class="btn btn-fleximaal-dark" ng-click="addInvoice(); false" ng-hide="document">Factuur toevoegen</button>
            <button class="btn btn-fleximaal-dark" ng-click="addDocument(); false" ng-show="document">Document toevoegen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

i hope someone can help me out to build a check. If data gives error 0 the fields are correct filled.

Comment: Please create a [Mcve]. Also, how in the world am I supposed to even read what your code sais with that formatting?

Comment: If you can edit the database using SQL, add `NOT NULL` to the end of each `INSERT INTO [TABLE] VALUES` query. This will disallow empty input values.

Comment: @MaxVoisard We are using a API just need to build a if statement but i dont know where to check on...

Comment: The code you commented out references `null` values, and quite possibly may be code that denies those empty strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omit empty strings from serializeArray in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324589/omit-empty-strings-from-serializearray-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your lines (in the `if` and `else`) of JavaScript where you declare the `serializeArray()` variable using jQuery. You had:

```
var formdata = $("").serializeArray();
```

Instead, it should be something like:

```
var formdata = $("input[value!=''],checkbox[value!=''],radio[value!=''],select[value!='']").serializeArray();
```